# Unable to uninstall SVN on fedora 21

Tags: svn, fedora, rhel

```
$svn --version

svn, version 1.8.13 (r1667537)
   compiled May 20 2015, 15:27:45 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Copyright (C) 2014 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people;
see the NOTICE file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme

$sudo yum remove subversion
Loaded plugins: langpacks
No Match for argument: subversion
No Packages marked for removal
```

This seems to be strange as I have svn installed but yum cant uninstall it.

Comment: Are you sure `yum` was used to install `subversion`? [Fedora's Package Database](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=752) doesn't show that version for F21.  What does `yum list subversion` show?

Comment: Also you can check which package (if any) own svn executable by running `rpm -qf $(which svn)`.